# How do I concatenate a calculated result to some existing text in Twig?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have several variables available that allow me to display years. For example,

```
{{ vars['cotisation_max_year'] }} => 2016
```

I have another variable that look like the following:

```
{{ vars.cotisations['cotisation_2014'] }}
```

That display a query's result.

If I do `{{ vars['cotisation_max_year'] - 1 }}`, I get 2015, and if I do

```
{% set annee = vars['cotisation_max_year'] %} // Let's simplify
{{ vars.cotisations['cotisation_' ~ annee ] }}
```

I get the result for 2016. However, if I do the following:

```
{{ vars.cotisations['cotisation_' ~ annee - 1 ] }}
```

Nothing shows up.

Is there a way to display the result anyway? I couldn't find anything that would solve my problem on the Twig documentation or on SO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this instead of complicate the code:

```
{% set annee = vars['cotisation_max_year'] -1 %} // Let's simplify
{{ vars.cotisations['cotisation_' ~ annee ] }}
```

Or this (never tried):

```
{% set annee = vars['cotisation_max_year'] %} // Let's simplify
{{ vars.cotisations['cotisation_' ~ (annee - 1) ] }}
```

Comment: Thank you, the second proposition worked! (I'm sorry, SO doesn't allow me to accept your answer before 10mn)